# window.location.href does not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have to scroll up in a page. Therefore I put a an anchor at the correct place and then I did

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.org/#anchor';
```

This works fine with FF, Chrome, Safari and IE9. But in IE8 nothing happens (it does not scroll).

I also tried:

```
window.location.hash = "anchor";
window.location.hash = "#anchor";
scrollTo(0, 0);
```

However, IE8 just does not want to scroll. It is important that we move the focus to the anchor. A reloading is not possible.

Thanks in advance for any tipps :)

Comment: Have you tried the ".scrollIntoView()" method on the element?

Comment: @Pointy then I would have to get the anchor element first right? I tried a similar solution with a <div id="anchor"> and then get that element and call scrollIntoView on it. It does not work :(

Comment: I've used "scrollIntoView" in IE many times and it has always worked fine for me.  Maybe if you could prepare a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) people could help investigate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For IE 8 just use it like this, it will work:

```
window.location = 'http://example.org/#anchor';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is unbelievable. Now it works in Safari, Chrome, IE8, IE9 but NOT in firefox...

Comment: What about `window.location = '#';`?